# How to optimize this python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, optimization

I new to python programming.How to optimize this code? It also gives an error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'list1' referenced before assignment.but if I define list1 outside the loop it takes too much time to execute for large lists.

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    list2 = []
    for i in range(len(ints)):
        if i == len(ints) - 1:
            break
        for j in range(i + 1, len(ints)):
            if i != j and (ints[i] + ints[j] == s):
                list1 = []
                if list2 == []:
                    list1[0:2] = ints[i], ints[j]
                    list2[0:2] = i, j
                elif list2[-1] > j:
                    list1[0:2] = ints[i], ints[j]
                    list2[0:2] = i, j

                break
     if list1 == []:
        return None
    return list1
print(sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10))
```

I am writing a function which returns the first two values (parse from the left please) in order of appearance that adds up to form the sum. for example:

```
  **sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10)
 #                 ^-----------^   5 + 5 = 10, indices: 1, 5
 #                       ^--^      3 + 7 = 10, indices: 3, 4 *
 #  * entire pair is earlier, and therefore is the correct answer
 == [3, 7]**
```

Comment: Can you give insight about what you want the function to do?

Comment: A few problems I can see without any idea about what you're trying to do: You keep overwriting `list1` by setting it to `[]` within the `for` loop. That may not be what you want. Also `if i is not j` should be `if i != j` - you need to test for equality, not object identity. Also, your indentation is off.

Comment: I am writing a function which returns the first two values (parse from the left please) in order of appearance that adds up to form the sum. for ex. sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5],         10)
#              ^-----------^   5 + 5 = 10, indices: 1, 5
#                    ^--^      3 + 7 = 10, indices: 3, 4 *
#  * entire pair is earlier, and therefore is the correct answer
== [3, 7]

Comment: your list1 looks like it's not defined in the scope can you please validate the indentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can't use a slice on `list1` if `list1` is not defined, so instead of writing `list1[0:2] = ints[i], ints[j]`, you should write `list1 = [ints[i], ints[j]]`.
Second, the algorithm itself is not efficient. Instead of looping on all values, and for every value do a loop again, which has O(n²) complexity, using a set and doing a single loop has O(n log n) complexity.

Take a look at the following code which is much more efficient:

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    encountered = set()
    for i in range(len(ints)):
        if s-ints[i] in encountered:
            return [s-ints[i], ints[i]]
        encountered.add(ints[i])

print(sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5], 10))
```

This gives: `[3, 7]`